# Как сделать подобную верстку?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Каким образом сделать подобную верстку на странице?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинкой с прозрачной частью? но тогда она будет большой, а как же пустое место под ней?

Буду благодарен за информацию, примеры.

Comment: Градиентом можно сделать. Или svg.

Comment: @Qwertiy можно пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden; /* clearfix */
  background: linear-gradient(.4636476090008061rad, white 50%, black 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(.4636476090008061rad, white 50%, black calc(50% + 1px));
  color: white;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-indent: 3em;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  padding-top: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>Тут будет меню!</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Например, при помощи градиента, быстро и читаемо.

```css
.menu {
    width: 300px;
    height: 106px;
    background: linear-gradient(19deg, transparent 100px, #444 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

nav:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #00A8F3;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
}

ul {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;    
    justify-content: center;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Не поддерживается в IE.

Comment: можно использовать polyfill - https://github.com/AlfonsoFilho/ClipPath

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menu {
  width: calc(100%);
  height: calc(50vh);
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(10deg, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0)50%, hsla(40, 80%, 15%, 1)52%);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">Меню</div>
```

Comment: Подберите угол смещения в linear-gradient(10deg <---- как вам нужно...